# Remove class when user clicks wherever on the page

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have 2 button which will toggle/remove class when user clicks on it.

```
$('.social-toggle').on('click', function() {
  $('.social-networks').not($(this).next()).removeClass('open-menu')
  $(this).next().toggleClass('open-menu');
});
```

Clicking on another share button will open another box at the same time the first is closed.
But want Clicking anywhere outside the box close them. Do yo know how can i do that?
Also here is my HTML

```
<div class="share-button">
  <a href="#" class="social-toggle">Share</a>
<div class="social-networks">
  <ul>
    <li class="social-twitter">
      <a href="http://www.twitter.com">T</a>
    </li>
    <li class="social-facebook">
    <a href="http://www.facebook.com">F</a>
    </li>
    <li class="social-gplus">
    <a href="http://www.gplus.com">G+</a>
    </li>
  </ul>
</div>
   </div>
```

[JSFIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/1fr85wf8/4/)

Comment: Use `.blur()` instead

Comment: Related: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/152975/how-to-detect-a-click-outside-an-element. Use that to remove the class.

Comment: @ZeeTee: `blur` is the opposite of focus, not clicking.

Comment: Pretty sure for what OP wants it will work

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could register a click handler for the document, then check whether the target was a `.social-toggle`(to prevent double processing - another option is to stop the propagation of click from `.social-toggle` handler.) element if not close the opened `.social-networks` element.

```
$(document).click(function (e) {
    if (!$(e.target).hasClass('social-toggle')) {
        $('.social-networks.open-menu').removeClass('open-menu')
    }
})
```

Demo: [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/3gctdkcv/)

---

Using propagation(not a fan of this approach because if you need similar functionality in another part of the page that will be broken if you stop the propogation)

```
$('.social-toggle').on('click', function (e) {
    e.stopPropagation();
    $('.social-networks').not($(this).next()).removeClass('open-menu')
    $(this).next().toggleClass('open-menu');
});

$(document).click(function (e) {
    $('.social-networks.open-menu').removeClass('open-menu')
})
```

Demo: [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/3gctdkcv/2/)